# Launch VR Oculus app from another VR Oculus app

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, deep-linking, virtual-reality, oculus

I have 2 apps developed in Unity/C# for VR/Oculus

I want to launch one from another 
(both of them aren't in the offical Oculus store yet).

I found this guide: [Integrate App Deeplinking](https://developer.oculus.com/documentation/platform/latest/concepts/dg-deeplinking/)

1. Is it the only way?
2. I added the next snippet to my project:

   ```
   var options = new ApplicationOptions();
   options.SetDeeplinkMessage("abc");
   Platform.Application.LaunchOtherApp(<app_id>, options);
   ```

   But the IDE isn't recognize `ApplicationOptions` and `Platform`
   what am I missing?
3. What is the `app_id`, I mean, from where I should get it?

Answer (score 2):

You should have the namespaces in the `using` section, or try this:

```cs
var options = new Oculus.Platform.ApplicationOptions();
options.SetDeeplinkMessage("abc");
Oculus.Platform.Application.LaunchOtherApp(<app_id>, options);
```

If this doesn't work, check if you have the `Unity Integration` package from Oculus.

Also, you can get the `app_id` from the Oculus Dashboard of your app.

Comment: how do you get Ulong app id? All i get is a string

Answer (score 0):

you should initialize the platform in your function
Oculus.Platform.Core.AsyncInitialize();
you should also have your app_id set in the unity editor before uploading the build in the store